# Why would commands in selenium works seperately but if put in script selenium does'nt locate the elements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

The problem i am facing is when i run the whole script it throws error of element not clickable or not found. While when i run it command per command it works.

If anyone can explain the reason and why it behaves this way i ll be very grateful.

codeExample:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id=\'Content_C164_Col00\']/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/button/span/span/span[3]").click()
driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "fxs_c_datepicker_button")[1].click()
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "fxs_btn.fxs_btn_cta.fxs_fRight").click()
```

ERROR:

ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (238, 772). Other element would receive the click: ...
(Session info: chrome=101.0.4951.64)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:

*I am working in VS code as my editor.*

Comment: Your error suggests the element you're trying to click is being blocked by another element. Possibly a popup appears or the element is at the border of your viewport. What you could try is scrolling to the element before clicking it and making sure by watching your code run that nothing is blocking that element.

Comment: If you could provide the website or html, i could give possibly you a more specific answer.

Comment: https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar

Comment: the thing is that if i run the comands one by one it works perfectly

Comment: Which element click is getting intercepted? The "fxs_btn.fxs_btn_cta.fxs_fRight" button?

Comment: ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <span>...</span> is not clickable at point (238, 772).

Comment: the first line button is intercepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced your problem and had the same error.  What i did to fix it is just scroll to the element before clicking it.
Try this out

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id=\'Content_C164_Col00\']/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/button/span/span/span[3]").click()
driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "fxs_c_datepicker_button")[1].click()

actions = ActionChains(driver)

button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "fxs_btn.fxs_btn_cta.fxs_fRight")
actions.move_to_element(button)
button.click()
```

I also noticed that after a few seconds a popup appears on the website. Make sure you click that one away as it may intercept the click on the apply button.

Update:
Here's the full code from opening the website to selecting date and clicking the apply button.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

# Opening browser and maximizing it
driver.get("https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar")
driver.maximize_window()

# Click 'Continue to site'
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "fxs_prestitial-continue").click()

# Wait until popup appears and cancel it
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@id='onesignal-slidedown-cancel-button' and text()='Cancel']").click()

# Click the datepicker button and choose date
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id=\'Content_C164_Col00\']/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/button/span/span/span[3]").click()
driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "fxs_c_datepicker_button")[1].click()

# Creating actions instance
actions = ActionChains(driver)

# Scrolling to 'Apply' button and clicking it
button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "fxs_btn.fxs_btn_cta.fxs_fRight")
actions.move_to_element(button)
button.click()
```

Comment: thanks , i appreciate it howver it feels it's something related to "copy_disclaimer"

Comment: I added the full code i used to my answer. It works perfectly on my machine. Let me know if it does for you aswell.

Comment: unfortunately, it does'nt always work,    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@id='onesignal-slidedown-cancel-button' and text()='Cancel']"}

Comment: Make the implicit wait longer, it may take longer on your machine to load. change this line 'driver.implicitly_wait(10)' to 'driver.implicitly_wait(30)'

Answer (score 0):

I tested a new version that works:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onesignal-slidedown-cancel-button"))).click()

while True:
    try:
        studio = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "fxs_headline_tiny").text
        # print(studio)
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 450)")
        driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "fxs_icon.fa-calendar-alt.fa-w-14").click()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        exact_date = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "fxs_c_datepicker_button")
        for i in range(len(exact_date)):
            exact_date_i = exact_date[i].text
            if(exact_date_i == "Today"):
                time.sleep(2)
                exact_date[i].click()
                break

            
        break
    except:
        print("Studio not found")
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "fxs_btn.fxs_btn_cta.fxs_fRight").click()
```